In a Power Platform Environment, what is the difference between a "Microsoft Entra ID Office Group" and a "Microsoft Entra ID Security Group"?
I am working in the Power Platform admin center, configuring an Environment. I want to create a Team to set granular permissions. On the "New team" panel, one option is the "Team type". My choices include "Microsoft Entra ID Office Group" and "Microsoft Entra ID Security Group". I know that Entra ID is the new name for Azure Active Directory. But I have a few questions.

What is the difference between an Office Group and a Security Group?
If I create one of these Teams/Groups within the Environment interface, can
I add or remove users to the group outside of this Environment, like in Entra ID?
If I have an existing Entra ID group, can I add it as a Team?

